# Fastest Get data from remote server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, performance, ado.net

I'm creating a windows application in which I need to get data using ado.net/(Or any other way using C# if any ). From one table. The database table apparently has around `100000` records and it takes forever to download.

Is there any faster way where I could get data into faster?

I tried the `DataReader` but still isn't fast enough.

Comment: What means _download_? Show what you have tried, 100000 is not much.

Comment: If it's your database query that's taking long, then you can always look into setting up indexes on your tables.

Comment: If the underlying connection and/or database is slow, it's not going to matter what class/method you use.

Comment: try the options for SqlDataReader like SequentialDataAccess.

Comment: Don't use reader?  Have you tried using a SQLDataAdapter and filling a DataTable or DataSet?  At some point you need to actually improve your SQL (T or PL) and probably look into stored proceedures to improve upon what you are doing on the server side, which may or may not improve your performace of getting the data over a network.  I retaged your question with SQL.

Comment: What type of database are you using, what kind of client API, what does your SQL look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data-reader API is about the most direct you can do. The important thing is *where is the time?*

- is it bandwidth in transferring the data?
- or is it in the fundamental query?

You can find out by running the query locally on the machine, and see how long it takes. If bandwidth is your limit, then all you can really try is removing columns you don't actually need (don't do `select *`). Or pay for a fatter pipe between you and the server. In **some cases**, querying the data locally, and returning it in some compressed form might help - but then you're really talking about something like a web-service, which has other bandwidth considerations.

More likely, though, the problem is the query itself. Often, things like:

- writing sensible tsql
- adding an appropriate index
- avoid cursors, complex processing, etc

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement a need to know basis method. Only pull down the first chunk of data that is needed and then when the next set is needed, pull those rows.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably your query that is so slow not the streaming process. You should show us your sql query, then we could  help you to improve it.

Assuming you want to get all 100000 records from you table, you could use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable` or a `SqlDataReader` to fill a `List<YourCustomClass>`:

the `DataTable` approach (since i don't know your fields it's difficult to show a class):

```
var table = new DataTable();
const string sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable ORDER BY SomeColumn";
using(var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
using(var da  = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
{
    da.Fill(table);
}
```